# Displaying CAD images with javascript

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

After a couple of days searching i decide to come here to ask if someone knows how to display 3D images (CAD images) in a website using only javascript.

My goal is to display .stp or .igs formats and allow user to interact with.

So far I've found a couple of frameworks:

https://github.com/tbuser/thingiview.js

http://threejs.org/

https://github.com/humu2009/jsc3d

But they are outdated or they don't allow me to display the formats mentioned.

Does anyone had a similar problem to this that can share how to work with?

Another possibility I've thought is to extract jpg images from the above formats and display it with a 360 image view plugin such as:

http://reel360.org/reel

http://spritespin.ginie.eu/

(to mention a few)

**Pros:**

- loads faster
- easier to implement

**Cons:**

- Need to convert to jpg
- More difficult to implement
- Outdated frameworks (except Three.js)

**note:** I don't need to have any interaction with the image such as go inside the image, make it transparent, explode... I just have to be able to display it like a 360 picture.

Do you have a nice way to achieve this?

Any comments would be helpful.
Thank in advance,

André

Comment: What's the question? Also, it might be helpfull for you to read [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: You should probably say that these are CAD models instead of 3d images because this is not a vanilla 3d problem.

Comment: @joojaa you're right. I edited the question. Thank you for your time and answer.

Comment: You can try this cloud service (currently in Beta) to automate raster image generation: http://ews.devdept.com

Answer (score 2):

Step and IGES are cad formats and most 3d development in webgl is game development. This is on the other side of the art/games tech divide, the CAD format does not describe polygonal models*. So any program that could show these formats would need to have a geometric solver back end called a CAD kernel. No basic 3D framework will do for you. This is on the other side of simple 3D.

STEP is also a hideously complex format doing a importer is hard even with a CAD kernel. I would look for something like [opencascade](http://www.opencascade.com/) for the job of converting the cad data to polygons for display. Generally speaking there aren't many free B-Rep backends.

You could also use your existing cad app to do this. I doubt you will find a pure javascript version of a CAD kernel.

* think of it like this a normal 3d model is mostly polygonal. But a B-Rep model does not describe polygons but rather the interconnection of mathematical shapes. So before you can display a step of iges file you need to solve it. Start by reading [this](http://www.opencascade.com/doc/occt-7.0.0/overview/html/occt_user_guides__step.html)